# how to flatten a tree and build a path from properties?

Tags: json, recursion, tree, jq

My goal is it to flatten a filesystem like structure (nested directories) with history information for individual files into a csv file for further processing. [Here](https://jqplay.org/s/XoZXoqQPB_) is what i tried so far.

The simplified input looks like this:

```
{ "dirs": [
    { 
        "name": "documents",
        "files": [
            {
                "name": "foo.bar",
                "history": [
                    { "hash": "123", "timestamp": "..."},
                    { "hash": "234", "timestamp": "..."}
                ]
            }
        ],
        "subDirs": [
            { "name": "tmp", "files": [...], "subDirs": [...]
            }
        ]        
    }
]}
```

The **tricky part** is that the csv file should contain full directory paths, not only the directory name. The desired output looks like this:

```
"documents","foo.bar","123","..."
"documents","foo.bar","234","..."
"documents","bar.baz","345","..."
"documents","bar.baz","456","..."
"documents/tmp","deleteme","567","..."
"documents/tmp","deleteme","678","..."
```

flattening most of the data by using `recurse` works using this query:

```
.dirs[] | recurse(.subDirs[]?) | . as $d | $d.files[]? as $f | $f.history[]? as $h | [$d.name, $f.name, $h.hash, $h.timestamp] | @csv
```

...but i cannot wrap my head around how i can preserve build the directory path. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to define a custom recursive function for this, like below; which assumes that all files have a non-empty `history`.

```
def f(pfix):
    ( [ pfix, .name ] | join("/") ) as $path |
    ( .files[] | .history[] as $hist | [ $path, .name, $hist[] ] ),
    ( .subDirs[] | f($path) );
.dirs[] | f(empty) | @csv
```

Comment: This works perfectly. thank you very much! i kind of went to a dead end with 'recurse'

Comment: @oguzismail - With the sample data at jqplay, your solution produces an error, which can be resolved by writing `.history[]?`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that neither uses recursion explicitly (*) nor relies on a recursive structure:

```
def names($path):
  reduce getpath($path[0:range(0; $path|length)]) as $v ("";
    if $v | type == "object" and has("name") then . + "/" + $v["name"] else . end) ;

paths as $p
| getpath($p) as $v
| select($v | objects | has("history"))
| [names($p), getpath($p + ["name"])]
  + ($v["history"][] | [.hash, .timestamp] )
| @csv
```

This produces "absolute" paths (e.g. "/documents"); omitting the leading "/" can be accomplished easily enough.

---

(*) `paths` is defined recursively but in a way that takes advantage of jq's tail-call optimization (TCO), which is only applied to arity-0 recursive functions.

Comment: thanks for your take on this. it's easier to grasp but i already solved my problem using oguz's answer. I'm still learning jq so looking at different solutions definitely helps.

Comment: @Buxel considering the downsides of recursion this is probably -didn't test but still- not only a different solution but also a better one in terms of performance

Comment: @oguzismail - For problems such as this, unoptimized recursion is fine.  It's only when the recursion depth is large that it starts to matter.

Comment: so basically `paths` uses TCO automatically to optimize the otherwise unoptimized (manual) recursion? I'll do some reading about TCO, thanks!